How to add a title to a plot in ploty using a pandas histogram
I am trying to add a title to my plot but it's not working.
data.hist(by=['ascites', 'sex', 'drug'])
plt.title('Ascites Distribution')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Number of Patients')
plt.show()

The title and xlabel are not showing.


Does this answer your question? How to set common axes labels for subplots

THis is how to do this correctly:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'ascites': np.random.choice(['Yes', 'No'], size=100),
    'sex': np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], size=100),
    'drug': np.random.choice(['Drug1', 'Drug2'], size=100),
    'Age': np.random.randint(20, 60, size=100)
})

axes = data.hist(by=['ascites', 'sex', 'drug'], figsize=(10, 8), layout=(4, 2), xrot=45)

plt.gcf().suptitle('Ascites Distribution', fontsize=16, y=1.02)
for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.set_xlabel('Age', fontsize=12)
    ax.set_ylabel('Number of Patients', fontsize=12)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()




Thank you are there more resources to learn more about matplotlib.pyplot as plt that you can recommend.  This solution worked.
